# How do you fix and error of an Invalid version of NPM for installing @nestjs/core?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, npm-scripts, npm-start

Hey so i just recently started learning Nestjs and I was asked to setup the environment on my Chromebook(Linux terminal). All packages have been successfully installed except a package *@nesjs/core*. I've tried running the command to install the package **npm install @nestjs/core** but anytime i run the command it keeps giving me this error:

```
npm ERR! Invalid Version: 
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/jefferson/.npm/_logs/2022-07-09T07_13_30_344Z-debug-0.log
```

So far I've tried changing my version of npm to version 6.2.0, deleting and reinstalling nodejs and npm but there's been no positive result.

Please what else should I try doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Node version is very recent, try downgrading. Stable version 14.16.1 worked.

Comment: Thank so much @Abhay this really worked. I also had to change my version of npm that was compatible with the version of node. This reply is verified to be a valid answer !